# JavaFX scaling chart series units

Tags: java, javafx-2

Hi i have a JavaFX LineChart and i want to redraw the series using different units, i create a separate list calculate the new values using a conversion factor, remove all values and add the new values.

This works great except that now the first point is connected to the previous last point, that was already removed.

Any ideas how to avoid this?

```
for(XYChart.Series<Number, Number> series : _chart.getData())
{
    List<XYChart.Data<Number, Number>> data = series.getData();
    List<XYChart.Data<Number, Number>> newData = 
                                  new ArrayList<XYChart.Data<Number, Number>>();
    for(XYChart.Data<Number, Number> item : data)
    {
        newData.add(new XYChart.Data<Number, Number>(
                              item.getXValue(), 
                              item.getYValue().floatValue() * conversionFactor));
    }
    series.getData().remove(0, series.getData().size() - 1);
    for(XYChart.Data<Number, Number> item : newData)
    {
        series.getData().add(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear data first by `series.getData().clear()`. Also you can use `ObservableList` to avoid adding loop.

```
for (XYChart.Series<Number, Number> series : chart.getData()) {
    List<XYChart.Data<Number, Number>> data = series.getData();
    ObservableList<XYChart.Data<Number, Number>> newData =
            FXCollections.<XYChart.Data<Number, Number>>observableArrayList();
    for (XYChart.Data<Number, Number> item : data) {
        newData.add(new XYChart.Data<Number, Number>(
                item.getXValue(),
                item.getYValue().floatValue() * 1.1));
    }
    series.getData().clear();
    series.setData(newData);
}
```

Comment: Seems that i can also use item.setYValue(item.getYValue().floatValue() * 1.1), any pros/cons of using setYValue. regards.